# I want to create audit log using fastapi in python

Tags: python, fastapi, audit-logging

I have created a few tables in sqlalchemy. I want to build an audit log for these tables to capture the history. Whenever a table is updated with values or inserted values, these logs needs to be captured in another audit table. How could I achieve this using sqlalchemy.

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper
from sqlalchemy import event
from models import user_log

@event.listens_for(Usermodel, "after_insert")
def insert_user_log(mapper, connection, target):
    po =user_log
    connection.exicute(po.insert().values(user_id=target.id, action='insert'))


@event.listen_for(user,"after update")
def update_user_log(mapper,connection,target):
    po=user_log
    connection.exicute(po.insert().values(user_id=target.id,action='update'))    


@event.listen_for(Usermodel,"after delete")
def update_user_log(mapper,connection,target):
    po=user_log
    connection.exicute(po.insert().values(user_id=target.id,action='delete'))
```

Comment: Amita, you can also use trigger functions to capture the logs and insert them into the audit table. This is just an idea, please do some research before using triggers.

Comment: You have provided some code. Does it work? If not, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @M.O. i tried that code but that is not working proper.

Comment: @MadhanKumarR Trigger functions i can only use in mysql database but i want to do through fasatapi.

Comment: Then call the code that updates audit in places, whenever you do any operation on db

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can indeed leverage SQLAlchemy to accomplish this task in FastAPI.

In FastAPI, you can utilize middleware to implement the required functionality. Additionally, a few modules will be necessary for creating the database module and schema.

### Modules:

- `database.py`: This module is responsible for interacting with and executing all the SQLAlchemy logic.
- `modules.py`: This module is used to build the database schema.

#### Functions:

- `get_db`: A dependency that creates a new SQLAlchemy `SessionLocal` for each request, closing it once the request is completed.
- `db_session_middleware`: A function executed for each request, with code executed both before and after the endpoint function.
- `store_audit`: Responsible for storing auditing information in the database.

##### module.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ARRAY, Tuple
from app.database import Base



class Audit(Base):
    __tablename__ = "audit"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    url = Column(String)
    headers = Column("headers", ARRAY(String))
    method = Column(String)
    response = Column(String)
```

##### database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


DATABASE = 'postgresql'
USER = 'user'
PASSWORD = 'user'
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = '5432'
DB_NAME = 'postgres'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f'postgresql://{USER}:{PASSWORD}@{HOST}/{DB_NAME}'

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

session_local = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

##### main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from fastapi import Response
from fastapi.requests import Request
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from app import models
from app.database import engine, session_local
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session


class Book(BaseModel):
    title: str = Field(min_length=1)
    author: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=100)
    description: str = Field(min_length=1, max_length=100)
    rating: int = Field(gt=-1, lt=101)


app = FastAPI()

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


# Dependency
def get_db(request: Request):
    return request.state.db


@app.middleware("http")
async def db_session_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    response = Response("Internal server error", status_code=500)
    try:
        request.state.db = session_local()
        response = await call_next(request)
        response_body = b''
        if all(filter not in request.url.__str__() for filter in ['docs', 'openapi.json', 'favicon.ico']):
            async for chunk in response.body_iterator:
                response_body += chunk
            response = Response(content=response_body, status_code=response.status_code,
                                headers=dict(response.headers), media_type=response.media_type)
            await store_audit_middleware(request, response_body, request.state.db)
    finally:
        request.state.db.close()
    return response


async def store_audit_middleware(request: Request, response_body, db):
    audit_entry = models.Audit()
    audit_entry.url = request.url.__str__()
    audit_entry.headers = request.headers.items()
    audit_entry.method = request.method
    audit_entry.response = response_body.decode()
    db.add(audit_entry)
    db.commit()
    return audit_entry
```

### References:

- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

### my demo auditing demo repository:

- https://github.com/dannielshalev/fastapi_alchemy_auditing_demo