# Audit trail in fastapi using mysql database,How to call auditlog in FastAPI? but not using trigger in mysql using fastapi if method of auditlog

Tags: mysql, fastapi, audit, audit-logging, audit-trail

how to create audit log in fastapi using mysql table .and add users old value and new value with the timing and user name in mysql table.this is my code of create,update,delete user code.and models.py file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: similar questions and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75008859/i-want-to-create-audit-log-using-fastapi-in-python